# Convert real distance to Google Map distance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location, maps

I have a `marker` on a Google Map (Android) and I want to move the marker to a new position given `bearing` and `distance`.

```
//lat, lng in degrees. Bearing in degrees. Distance in Km
private LatLng newPostion(Double lat,Double lng,Double bearing,Double distance) {
      Double R = 6371; // Earth Radius in Km

       Double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * lat) * Math.cos(distance / R) + Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * lat) * Math.sin(distance / R) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * bearing));
       Double lon2 = Math.PI / 180 * lng + Math.atan2(Math.sin( Math.PI / 180 * bearing) * Math.sin(distance / R) * Math.cos( Math.PI / 180 * lat ), Math.cos(distance / R) - Math.sin( Math.PI / 180 * lat) * Math.sin(lat2));

       Double newLat = 180 / Math.PI * lat2;
       Double newLng = 180 / Math.PI * lon2;

       LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(newLat, newLng);

       return newLatLng;
} 

LatLng newPos = newPostion(myMark.getPosition().latitude,myMark.getPosition().longitude, 90.0,3000.0);
```

Distance is calculated speed * time.

```
distance = speed * time
```

Let's say the marker represents a car and the car goes 100 km/h and I need to update the marker every 5 seconds.

```
distance = 100 * (5/60)
```

but the problem is showing `distance` on Google map because Google maps are scaled. Using distance calculated above to move the marker will move the marker much further.

Can anyone help me to convert real distance to Google map distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your distance calculation, you're mixing seconds with minutes (5 seconds, 60 minutes). It should be:

```
distance = 100 km * (5 sec / 3600 sec)
```

Comment: wohaa, spent hours on this. Thanks a bunch! :)